Panda3d: как создать пустую сцену, не загружая модель?
Начал учить panda3d. В их туториалах сцена создается и включается с помощью строчек
self.scene = self.loader.loadModel("models/environment")
self.scene.reparentTo(self.render)

в которых первый метод загружает какую-то модель. Можно ли как-то сделать сцену без загрузки чего-либо, чтобы в итоге отображался просто белый экран, на фоне которого можно что-то делать? self.loader.loadModel без аргументов не работает.
